# Skipping controller-methods without registering(skipping) it with RequestMatcher of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

[spring-boot-2.3.2](/questions/tagged/spring-boot-2.3.2)
[spring-security-5.3.5](/questions/tagged/spring-security-5.3.5)

I have a `JWtAuthFilter` extending from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which does the token validation part.

I have some controller methods that are open(not-secured).
Right now I'm registering all the url patterns that needs to be skipped from token validation using my `JWtAuthFilter`.

```java
 http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
     .addFilterBefore(LoginProcessingFilter("\login"),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
     .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter(SKIP_LIST, "\**"),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

If I do not register any of public url in `SKIP_LIST`, it require authentication.
Do we have any better approach for this?
Thanks